# viewDidLoad is called, but viewDidAppear is not, for pushed viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, lifecycle

I have an app where UIViewControllers are pushed onto a UINavigationController using pushViewController. Once in a while, seemingly randomly, the pushed view controller loads (I know this because viewDidLoad is called), but it doesn't actually appear (viewDidAppear is not called). The app enters a state where the new view controller isn't visible, but presumably is on the screen because I am unable to interact with the view controller behind it. In other words, the UI is completely non responsive, but the app continues to run (background and main thread events continue to fire, such as animations and network calls).

Anyone have any idea what could cause a situation like this? Or any ideas about how to go about debugging the cause?

Comment: Show some code of your push.

Comment: you need to present your view controller either using presentViewController or pushViewController method

Comment: if you have a subset of `UIViewController` and you intend to override the `–viewDidAppear:` method, you must to call the `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` method (if you have a subset of the subset you need to do that as well); otherwise you break the notification chain which could lead even improper behaviours.

Comment: have you found the solutions for this?